Can the tf_text tokenize/detokenize processes preserve whitespace between words?
I am trying to implement a tokenizer/detokenizer for NLP machine learning tasks using tensorflow_text, following tensorflow's official tutorial. However, I notice that spaces between words are not preserved when detokenizing a tokenized string. Preserving spaces is essential to correctly reconstruct a model's output. The following code demonstrates the issue:
import re
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tf_text

tokenizer = tf_text.BertTokenizer("vocab.txt", lower_case=True, keep_whitespace=True, token_out_type=tf.int32)
def tokenize(txt:list[str]):
    return tokenizer.tokenize(txt).merge_dims(1, 2)

def detokenize(tokens):
    # remove unknown and padding tokens from output strings
    def clean_text(txt:bytes):
        txt = txt.decode()
        txt = re.sub(r'\[(PAD)\]', '', txt)
        return txt
    
    txt = tf.strings.reduce_join(tokenizer.detokenize(tokens), axis=-1).numpy()
    txt = list(map(clean_text, txt))
    return txt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    txt = ["the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"]
    enc = tokenize(txt); print(enc)
    dec = detokenize(enc); print(dec)

Output -> ['the[UNK]quick[UNK]brown[UNK]fox[UNK]jumps[UNK]over[UNK]the[UNK]lazy[UNK]dog']
vocab.txt is a vocabulary lookup table used in the official tensorflow guide that can be found here.
I tried solving the issue myself by adding a new token " " inside vocab.txt, which fixed the tokenizer. However, the detokenizer till ignores the spaces, as though the new token does not exist. Output -> ['thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog']. Any insight on this question will be greatly appreciated.
